# NGINX controller : disabling slash merging

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I am trying to create an ingress to acces the rabbitMQ management dashboard. This is what I have so far:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-ingress
  namespace: rabbimq
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: "myhost.com"
      http:
          paths:
            - backend:
                service:
                  name: rabbitmq
                  port:
                    number: 15672
              path: "/rabbit(/|$)(.*)"
              pathType: Prefix
```

With this ingress I can acces to the dashboard but not completly.
RabbitMq can create this kind of URL:
myhost.com/rabbit/#/queues **/%2F/** my-queue

The %2F being the encoding of the default rabbitmq vhost. But NGINX seems to decode the vhost and since is a slash the URL look like this:
myhost.com/rabbit/#/queues **///** my-queue

Nginx will compress the 3 adjacent slashes into a single slash since it is the default behaviour.

Which leads to my question: How can I disable the merge of the slashes on an nginx controller ?

I know there is the `merge_slashes` that i need to set to off, but i can't figure how to do.

I tried adding this:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippets: |
      merge_slashes off;
```

In rabbitmq-ingress file but got this error from the nginx controller logs :
"merge_slashes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

I tried with this instead:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
      merge_slashes off;
```

I don't have any error but it still didn't resolve the issue.

How can I do ?